# How to resize an image while scrolling down?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Visualizing picture for the problem]

I have tried to visualize my problem in the picture above.

I have an ImageView in a ScrollView.
I have modified the start position so a part of the ImageView start above the screen, ScrollView.srollTo(0, [value > 0]).

The issue is:
I want to show the bitmap center cropped when the scroll view is on start position ie. like 90% of the bitmap. While scrolling down the ScrollView to top position (scrollY = 0) I want to decrease the image crop level and when reaching the top the whole image shall be visible, no cropping.

Comment: Your link requires people to sign in with their Google account and request access. You Should find some other way to gain 4 more reputation (you only need 10), and then post your image properly.

Comment: If you want to change the scale during scroll, I'd suggest setting the image scale type as "Matrix" and then change the matrix scale based on how much was scrolled already.

Comment: @Zerp thank for you tip, I have posted the image now.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply @Edson Menegatti. I have never work with the matrix scale type, I will try your suggestion

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to achieve a zoom effect?

Comment: @Zerp, yes the zoom effect is what I want to achieve, but not by pinch to zoom but "scroll to zoom". I used scaleType matrix as Edson Menegatti suggested to achieve the state on picture 1. Now Im working on scaling down the bitmap so the whole bitmap is visible when the ScrollView is scrolled to top position (scrollY = 0)